# how to get email address via html Agility Pack 2

Tags: c#, javascript, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

How can I catch an email address from a website ?

I try to catch a email from a website that seems its protected by some JavaScript...

Here is the HTML code :

```
<p class="email">
<a href="mailto:info@aryanaz.ir" class="email">
    info@aryanaz.ir
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script></a>
</p>
```

I use this code that catch protected value and it doesn't work :

```
              HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
  var Email = from HtmlNode n in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, 'mailto:')]")
                              select n;
                foreach (HtmlNode node in Email )
                {
                    string email = node.InnerHtml.Trim();

                    if (node.InnerHtml.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        ClassBase.ENonQuery("addfullvalueemail ", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, new SqlParameter[]
            {
                  new SqlParameter("@Email ",email ),                  

            });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is that the script you see when you hit "View source" on the site or is it from using the web inspector (or similar tool) to view the final html? HTMLAgilityPack won't help you if thats the final html since it can't execute javascript for you.

Comment: Yes I find it using Web-Inspector. you mean I can't get emails by HtmlAglilityPack ?

Comment: How can I get emails ? any Ideas ? Can I get the email that shows between A tag and beginning of Script Tag ? :  info@aryanaz.ir

Comment: You can't get emails that are encoded using javascript with HtmlAgilityPack. You'll need some way to execute that javascript first (you could have a look at Awesomium, PhantomJS or another headless browser for that)

Comment: If you look at the page source using "View source" instead then you will see how it looks before the javascript is executed and I'm pretty sure that you won't see info@aryanaz.ir anywhere in it. If so, then it is surely possible and their solution for protecting addresses suck.

Comment: You right and in View source mode the email address doesn't appear. Anyway do you know ANY way to get this info from this website ? any solution ? I really need this emails addresses.

Comment: As I said, look at http://www.awesomium.com/ or some other headless browser solution to execute the javascript for you and then use the source rendered there.

Comment: Email addresses in this case are not obfuscated without reason. Crawling a site to gather the emailaddresses against the site owner's wishes (because in that case they can provide a better way to send you the addresses) is against privacy laws.